# Comparing Nested Function return value to Parent Function argument

Tags: swift

Running through the Swift App Development course when I hit a snag with last problem in Function Lab.

Idea is to write a function that takes 4 Double arguments and return a String, while nesting a previous function that shares 3 identical arguments  and returned a Double. Parent Function compares the return value of the Nested func, and compares it to the 4th argument (less than), then returns one of 2 Strings.

```
func pacing(currentDistance: Double, totalDistance: Double, currentTime: Double, goalTime: Double) -> String {
    func calculatePace(currentDistance: Double, totalDistance: Double, currentTime: Double) -> Double {
        let predictedFinish = (currentTime / currentDistance) * totalDistance
        return predictedFinish
    }
    if calculatePace() <= goalTime {
        print("Keep it up!")
    } else {
        print("You've got to push harder!")
    }
}
```

The calculatePace() <= goalTime is getting me tripped up. Error I get is: Missing argument for parameter. I've tried referencing predictedFinish instead. Error I get it Use of Unresolved Identifier. I've tried calling the whole

```
calculatePace(currentDistance: Double, totalDistance: Double, currentTime: Double)
```

and the error I get is: Cannot convert value of type 'Double.Type' to expected argument type 'Double'.  Keep in mind that this is a beginners Class so I'm probably overthinking this. Any clues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 issues that keep this code from compiling for me. 1. is you are trying to call `calculatePace()` which doesn't exist (the actual function has 3 parameters), and 2. you are not actually returning a `String`. After fixing both of these issues, this code works fine for me.

```
func pacing(currentDistance: Double, totalDistance: Double, currentTime: Double, goalTime: Double) -> String {
        func calculatePace(currentDistance: Double, totalDistance: Double, currentTime: Double) -> Double {
            let predictedFinish = (currentTime / currentDistance) * totalDistance
            return predictedFinish
        }
        if calculatePace(currentDistance: currentDistance, totalDistance: totalDistance, currentTime: currentTime) <= goalTime {
            return "Keep it up!"
        } else {
            return "You've got to push harder!"
        }
    }
```

Comment: This absolutely was it. Parent function return value is not a string because the if else statement is what returns the string display and the nested function needed its parameters explicitly stated (i.e. currentDistance: currentDistance instead of currentDistance: Double).   Thanks!